# Is it possible to get the Standard deviation of a field in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have this query:

```
cursor = collection.aggregate(
  [
      {"$match": {"NAME":{"$in":NAMELIST}}},
      {
          "$group":
              {
                  "_id":"$NAME",
                  "average": {"$avg":"$Price"},                                                                              
                  "max": {"$max":"$Price"},
                  "min": {"$min":"$Price"},
                  "count": {"$sum": 1},
             }
     }
  ]
  )
```

Is it possible to get the standard deviation in a similar fashion?

Comment: Operator not currently available but will be released in future versions. Look at the JIRA for it [**here**](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5044) and the [**tests**](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/faf0663603ed7a27f8c726245b005caa50065f81) here.

Comment: In the JIRA issue @chridam mentioned, there is a link to a script that can achieve this via MapReduce

https://gist.github.com/RedBeard0531/1886960

Comment: @bryagm do you know how I would integrate the js into python?